# How do I draw a polygon in an info-beamer node.lua program?

Tags: lua, raspberry-pi, glsl

I have started experimenting with [the info-beamer software](https://info-beamer.com/doc/info-beamer) for Raspberry Pi.  It appears to have support for display PNGs, text, and video, but when I see GLSL primitives, my first instinct is to draw a texture-mapped polygon.

Unfortunately, I can't find the documentation that would allow me to draw so much as a single triangle using the shaders.  I have made a few toys using GLSL, so I'm familiar with the pipeline of setting transform matrices and drawing triangles that are filtered by the vertex and fragment shaders.

I have grepped around in [info-beamer-nodes on GitHub](https://github.com/dividuum/info-beamer-nodes) for examples of GL drawing, but the relevant examples have so far escaped my notice.

How do I use info-beamer's GLSL shaders on arbitrary UV mapped polygons?

Comment: Can you add more information about what you're trying to do? Maybe there is another way to implement that without using triangle meshes which are currently not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by the author of info-beamer it is clear that functions to draw arbitrary triangles are not available in info-beamer 0.9.1.

The specific effect I was going to attempt was a rectangle that faded to transparent at the margins.  Fortunately the 30c3-room/ example in the info-beamer-nodes sources illustrates a technique where we draw an image as a rectangle that is filtered by the GL fragment shader.  The 1x1 white PNG is a perfectly reasonable template whose color can be replaced by the calculations of the shader in my application.

While arbitrary triangles are not available, UV-mapped rectangles (and rotated rectangles) are supported and are suitable for many use cases.

I used the following shader:

```
uniform sampler2D Texture;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
uniform float margin_h;
uniform float margin_v;

void main()
{
  float q = min((1.0-TexCoord.s)/margin_h, TexCoord.s/margin_h);
  float r = min((1.0-TexCoord.t)/margin_v, TexCoord.t/margin_v);
  float p = min(q,r);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,p);
}
```

and this LUA in my node.render()

```
y = phase * 30 + center.y

shader:use {
margin_h=0.03;
margin_v=0.2;
}
white:draw(x-20,y-20,x+700,y+70)
shader:deactivate()

font:write(x, y, "bacon "..(phase), 50, 1,1,0,1)
```